# ¿Como detectar la pulsación de una tecla?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Conozco el evento `KeyPress`, pero deseo que detecte la tecla estando en cualquier parte del programa, podría poner este evento en todos los elementos del programa, pero deseo saber si hay alguna forma mas efectiva de hacer esto

Comment: por programa te refieres al form activo ? o sea que no tenga el foco un control especifico

Comment: precisamente me refiero a eso, que estando el foco activo en cualquier parte del programa se detecte la pulsación de la tecla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe un metodo que podria resolver el problema

[Form.ProcessCmdKey(Message, Keys) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey?view=netframework-4.7.2)

quedando algo como esto

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{

     if (keyData != Keys.Enter) 
     {
         return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
     }

     //resto codigo

     return true;
}
```

En este ejemplo se detecta si se presiona la tecla enter sin importar donde este el foco en el form

Este es un metodo, no un evento, por eso veras que se realiza el `override`, pero permite capturar los eventos de teclado de todo el form